# Caracteres especiales en password_hash

Tags: php7, wamp

Hay alguna forma o instrucción de que, al utilizar password_hash de PHP, el hash se genere sin caracteres especiales.
Estoy utilizando lo siguiente:

```
$mystring = "1234567890albertolira";

$options = [
   'cost' => 10,
];

$hash_generated = password_hash($mystring, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
```

Pero siempre se genera el hash con algún caracter especial:

```
$2y$12$MZLy2rdjGHA/IYkKJJGJrea9h619RCtLA2Ah0N0MlV4z5tMFlJVJm
$2y$12$r9YEOoscn88./yMQ0igA4utnbR5VajdsX6YY3wjDrHPFekv6w4v3O
$2y$12$JwFyb88Y4vTo3q2kPUW0LuOCgfU8K778yUO/LjXGd.Lt/JncXNzoi
$2y$12$Ez1o2Q5F55AZ6kbEBCoyeuOEI7lsuT6uJVztyf8Emh/uzDu7Gm4dq
```

Estoy trabajando con la versión 7.4.26 de PHP en WAMPSERVER

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes tú por *caracteres especiales* y por qué deberían evitarse cuando precisamente lo que hace la función es crear un hash de la contraseña que sea fuerte y en eso ayuda mucho eso que tú llamas *caracteres especiales*? ¿Qué problema te causan dichos caracteres?

Comment: Quiero generar un hash para utilizarlo como valor de una cookie de sesión, ese hash se genera de un string que tiene características únicas del usuario que ingresa, lo voy a guardar en base de datos (sesiones personalizadas) para luego llamarla en el encabezado de cada archivo y comparar esos datos únicos con el hash para evitar que ingresen desde computadores fuera de la red.
Los valores de las cookies de sesión sólo aceptan comas y puntos y el hash se genera con los caracteres */-, etc.

Comment: En ese caso lo que deberías generar es el hash de un token que guardarías en la base de datos. [Aquí tienes abundantes ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/549/5587982) para poder optar por la solución más segura con respecto a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Acabo de ojearlo, es bien extenso, de seguro consigo mucha ayuda, sobretodo en lo que respecta a SSL/HTTPS encryption del cual ya había comenzado a investigar.